# Ignore duplicate filenames in 'find' command

Tags: unix, command-line

I'm trying to zip up all HTML files together under a specified directory, ignoring file locations, but there is an error with my command that I don't know how to fix. It doesn't ignore duplicate filenames as I need it to.

The command:

```
find /home/ -type f -name "*.html" | zip -j all-html-files -@
```

The error:

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)
```

Causes of that error (if this helps)

```
zip warning:   first full name: /home/company/press/managed-saas-service.html

zip warning:  second full name: /home/company/press/2/managed-saas-service.html

zip warning: name in zip file repeated:managed-saas-service.html
```

Comment: Why are you deleting your answer when it gets closure votes and then post it again? Those closure votes were suggesting you to ask in [SU] as it fits better than here. Also, I suggested you to use `| sort -u` after the find command to solve this.

Comment: `sort -u` won't work here because the files have different paths.

Comment: Thanks @dogbane, I knew that someone would be able to help! You're right, sort -u didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, using `awk`:

```
find /home/ -type f -name "*.html" | awk -F/ '{a[$NF]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' | zip -j all-html-files -@
```

If multiple files with the same name are found, the last file found will be stored in the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

If -j causes problem, why not just cd in the zip dir first like:

cd /tmp/dir
zip -r -9 -v /tmp/bkp.zip .